# In branch-and-price, how to handle variables that have a cost with an offset?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am implementing a **branch-and-price** (or column-generation) algorithm. The variables (or columns) I generate during optimization have **a cost with an offset**. For example, if I want to introduce a new variable `xi` it has both a cost coefficient `ci` that scales with `xi` and a constant cost `ci'`:

> total cost = Sum (ci * xi + ci') for all i

My variables `xi` are continuous.

How should I handle this?

Is it necessary to reformulate the problem so that a variable's associated cost has no offset? For example, in order to guarantee that column generation leads to the optimal solution.

My first idea would be to generate variables in pairs: the original `xi` and an associated binary variable `bi`. Then add the additional constraint that `bi = 0` if `xi = 0` and `bi = 1` if `xi > 0`. Is this a reasonable approach? What are its downsides apart from introducing binary variables?

Comment: Take a look at [BCP](https://projects.coin-or.org/Bcp) project.

Comment: @serge_k: thanks, that's what I use

Comment: Did you try to ask at [OR-exchange](https://www.or-exchange.org/)?

Comment: @serge_k That seems like a better place to ask this question. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to introduce a fixed cost associated with the column? The column has a cost which is the combined fixed and variable costs of the subproblem that it corresponds to, as one particular extreme point.

Comment: Every decision variable `xi` corresponds to some activity and the value expresses the time you perform it. Activities have different fixed costs `ci'` and different variable costs `ci`. The variable cost corresponds to the time that you perform an activity, the fixed cost corresponds to the activity's startup cost. I don't see how I can leave the latter out of the cost function.